# OSS Twitter Clone written in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, twitter

Does anyone know of a twitter clone written in .NET (or ideally C#)?

I wanna experiment with a private twitter network between some friends and work colleagues.

Comment: I don't really understand how this is any more programming related than asking for an open source OS or browser.

Comment: Fair enough, but i'm asking for code... sounds like programming to me...

Comment: Maybe when there's a right answer Cherian

Answer (score 7):

http://www.yonkly.com/. Done with Asp.net mvc

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [Witty](http://code.google.com/p/wittytwitter/)?  It is a a Twitter client that matches you criteria, I am not aware of any server software though.

Answer (score 0):

I know [TeleTwitter](http://code.google.com/p/teletwitter/). Though its development is stalled, it does everything I need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any Twitter implementations in C#. If you are looking for C# twitter client, then Witty is the way to go (for now.. I'm working on a new one based on Witty libraries)

http://code.google.com/p/wittytwitter/